# Visual Studio 2015 wdk not breaking on driver debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, windbg, wdk

I have setup a host and a target windows 8.1 virtual machine using QEMU. When I boot the target I am able to see logs on windbg on the host. In visual studio 2015, when I attach the process and choose windows kernel mode debugger, I am so able to break and see the logs. However, the debugger does not break when I try installing the driver.

The following is what I do:

1. Set environmental variable _NT_SYBMBOL_PATH to 
   c:\symbols\driver;SRV*c:\symbols\websymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
2. Compile the driver
3. Generate the pdb files using `symstore add /f c:\users\admin\qc-driver\x64\Debug /s c:\symbols\driver /r`
4. Copy the Debug folder to the target machine
5. Start Kernel Mode Debugger using attach to process and break
6. press continue or type g for the debugger to continue
7. Switch to the target machine and on the command line use `pnputil -f -a qcu-driver.inf`

The driver installs but the debugger does not stop on the breakpoints I have set at DriverEntry. I have used `lm` and the driver is not loaded even after installing it. I have tried `.reload /f driver.sys` after running `!sym noisy` and I get this error:

```
0: kd> !sym noisy
noisy mode - symbol prompts off
0: kd> .reload /f qcu-driver

Press ctrl-c (cdb, kd, ntsd) or ctrl-break (windbg) to abort symbol loads that take too long.
Run !sym noisy before .reload to track down problems loading symbols.

"qcu-driver" was not found in the image list.
Debugger will attempt to load "qcu-driver" at given base 00000000`00000000.
Please provide the full image name, including the extension (i.e. kernel32.dll)
for more reliable results.Base address and size overrides can be given as
.reload <image.ext>=<base>,<size>.
DBGENG: qcu-driver - Partial symbol image load missing image info
DBGHELP: No header for qcu-driver. Searching for dbg file
DBGHELP: .\qcu-driver.dbg - file not found
DBGHELP: qcu-driver missing debug info. Searching for pdb anyway
DBGHELP: qcu-driver.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: Can't use symbol server for qcu-driver.pdb - no header information available
DBGHELP: Can't use symbol server for qcu-driver.pdb - no header information available
DBGHELP: Can't use symbol server for qcu-driver.pdb - no header information available
DBGHELP: qcu_driver - no symbols loaded
Unable to add module at 00000000`00000000
```

Can someone please shed some light, I am new to kernel debugging.

Comment: what does thsi mean Start Kernel Mode Debugger using attach to process and break   kd either requires com port or usb or net or 1394

Comment: On visual studio menu bar Debug->Attach to Process. I am using com port, com1.

Comment: Installing a driver doesn't necessarily load the driver. What kind of driver is this (i.e. PnP, legacy, WPF, fs filter, etc.)? You don't want .reload /f, if the module isn't in the list it isn't loaded. This can happen either because the driver isn't loaded or it tried to load and failed.

Comment: This is a kernel device driver non PnP built with WDF. I am trying to send "commands" to the host GPGPU using KVM guest driver to ultimately perform some computation using CUDA. This is working fine for linux VM, now I am trying to get it done on Windows.

Comment: Then you need to start the driver (e.g. "net start qcu-driver", or whatever the service name is). I would also highly suggest dumping VS as a kernel debugger and going directly to WinDbg. The VS integration is wonky and just add more complexity/annoyance